# How to reduce font size of TOC on lyx beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, lyx, fontsize

I am using a LyX beamer template which can be downloaded from [this link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/solutions/conference-talks).

I'm having trouble with a large TOC, which can't fit on one page. How can I reduce the font size of TOC, so that it can be fit on one page?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. 

For starters, you might want to surround the table of contents with a \begin{scriptsize} or tiny environment.

Comment: Does recluze's suggestion help? (Adding `\begin{scriptsize}` in an ERT before the TOC and `\end{scriptsize}` after.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a complete solution, as the numbers in the item bullets aren't reduced in size, but as suggested by recluze, putting the `\tableofcontents` in a `scriptsize` environment does reduce the font size of the text in the TOC. To do this:

1. Put the text cursor immediately before the `Table of Contents` object in LyX.
2. Add an ERT by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or Insert --> TeX code, and type

   ```
   \begin{scriptsize}
   ```

   in this.
3. Do the same immediately after the TOC object, and type

   ```
   \end{scriptsize}
   ```

   In LyX you'll see something like this:
   [image]

Without the ERTs, the result is

[image]

while with the ERTs you get

[image]

There are other sizes available, the smallest being `tiny`, followed by `scriptsize`,  `footnotesize`, `small` and then `normalsize`. The latter, as you may guess, is the standard size.

For reference, the larger sizes are `large`, `Large`, `LARGE`, `huge` and `HUGE`.

Answer (score 7):

You could split table of contents with parameters, such;

```
\tableofcontents[sections={1-4}]
```

and

```
\tableofcontents[sections={5-}]
```

in different frames.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the best way to control the font sizes of the elements of the toc is as follows:

```
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=fontsize}

\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=fontsize}

\setbeamerfont{subsubsection in toc}{size=fontsize}
```

where `fontsize` is one of `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, or `\Huge`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.